# How do I uninstall a desktop app for Firefox OS?

Tags: firefox, ubuntu, firefox-os, linux-mint

I have installed Internet Radio (from Firefox Marketplace) on my computer (with Linux Mint 17.1 Rebecca) but now, I want to uninstall it, what is the right way to do it? I can make right click on the main menu and choose uninstall option, but seems the app is not associated with any program to uninstall or something.

Comment: StackOverflow is more for programming related questions, not operating system specific questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux distros differ, but those that support [Desktop Actions](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#extra-actions) should uninstall the app when you select "uninstall" from the context menu.

I'm not sure why that isn't working for you, but a workaround, as described in [bug 761806, comment 60](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=761806#c60), is to invoke the app's executable with the *-remove* flag from a command line, something like:

```
~/.appname-hash/webapprt-stub -remove
```

Where *appname* is a recognizable descriptor for the app, and *hash* is an arbitrary string of characters.  On my Linux machine, [this InternetRadio app](https://marketplace.firefox.com/app/internetradio) installs to *~/.internetradio-08ac29b1795d0c93f780050049fbff0f*.

Also see [bug 896679](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=896679) for discussion of alternative interfaces for uninstalling an app on Linux (for distros that don't support desktop actions).

Comment: It worked perfectly! thank you so much. It also removes the app register from __~/.mozilla/firefox/{profile}/webapps/webapps.json__